# How to use onRequestPermissionsResult on not activity android?

Tags: android

my device marshmallow, so I should add get permission code.
my app camera preview app. 
Where get permission code, not activity.

so , I don't know how to use `onRequestPermissionsResult` on not Activity

my source

```
public class WebClient {
     public void readyCamera() {
         // camera releation work.
     }

     private void setCamera() {
          Activity activity = MainActivity.getMainActivity(); //get Activity

          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) { //over marshmallow
               if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity , Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { //no permission
                     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1000);
                     } else {
                          ActivityCompat.requeestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1000);
                     }
               } else {
                    readyCamera();
               }
            } readyCamera();
     }    

     @Override
     private void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
           switch (requestCode) {
               case 1000:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                         readyCamera();
                    } else {
                    }
            }
      }
```

how to use `onRequestPermissionsResult` method on not activity?

thanks:)

Comment: what you are using? fragment? or else.

Comment: if i understand correctly you can use Interface concept for notify any other code block to notify result.

Comment: The activity or fragment from which you are calling WebClient in that you can use onRequestPermissionsResult or in Splash activity also

Comment: @HemantParmar  WebClient only  class. MainActivity is activity. not fragment